# Is it possible to use 'LIKE' and '= ?' In the same SQL query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, ajax

I am creating a Filter function that sorts a list. I'm using ajax to return and display the results.

[image: Image example]

But I can't seem to find a way to return results when both the search input and an option have been set.

I keeping getting an error whenever I write my query like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM colaboradores where name LIKE :search% AND department = ? AND category = ? ORDER BY id DESC", nativeQuery = true)
List <Colaboradores> filterColaboradorBySearch(@Param("search")String search, int department, int category);
```

**ERROR:**

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.dexa.hr.repository.ColaboradorRepository.filterColaboradoresAll(java.lang.String,int,int)! Reason: Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?1 is not supported!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?1 is not supported!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1061) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:364) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:322) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:328) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 84 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?1 is not supported!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQuery$ParameterBindingParser.parseParameterBindingsOfQueryIntoBindingsAndReturnCleanedQuery(StringQuery.java:281) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQuery$ParameterBindingParser.access$000(StringQuery.java:182) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQuery.<init>(StringQuery.java:73) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.DeclaredQuery.of(DeclaredQuery.java:38) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryMethod.assertParameterNamesInAnnotatedQuery(JpaQueryMethod.java:158) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryMethod.<init>(JpaQueryMethod.java:139) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.DefaultJpaQueryMethodFactory.build(DefaultJpaQueryMethodFactory.java:44) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    ... 106 common frames omitted
```

I would like to know why.

Comment: You might want to tag your question with SQL and whatever SQL dialect you're using...

Comment: I would do this: onclick: create a JSON from the datas. If any data is not filled, then is null.
And create your query according to this JSON. Like concatenating the query's where statement with if statements

Comment: *I keeping getting an error whenever I write my query like this* Show **complete** error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with the mixing of `=` and `LIKE`.

This is happening because for one value (search) you're using `@Param` while for the other 2 attributes you're using a question mark as the placeholder.

Change to

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM colaboradores where name LIKE :search% AND department = :department AND category = :category ORDER BY id DESC", nativeQuery = true)
List<Colaboradores> filterColaboradorBySearch(@Param("search") String search, @Param("department") int department, @Param("category") int category);
```

or to

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM colaboradores where name LIKE ?1% AND department = ?2 AND category = ?3 ORDER BY id DESC", nativeQuery = true)
List<Colaboradores> filterColaboradorBySearch(String search, int department, int category);
```

Comment: Good answer. Please note that the OP used `name LIKE :search%` and therefore in your answer it should also be `name LIKE ?1%`